# Sort report by custom column in WooCommerce Analytics

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom column "Weight" in the Categories report of WooCommerce Analytics, giving the total weight of products sold in the given category.

As it can't be done using extra database select like suggested in [this article](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/02/04/adding-columns-to-analytics-reports-and-csv-downloads/) (as far as i understand), i used the `woocommerce_rest_prepare_report_[report-name]` hook as suggested [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/issues/5730#issuecomment-870859296) :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_report_categories', 'add_category_weight_in_rest', 10, 3 );
function add_category_weight_in_rest ($response, $report, $request ){
    
    $data = $response->get_data();
    $category_id = $data['category_id'];

    $params = $request->get_params();
    $after = $params['after'];
    $before = $params['before'];

    $data['category_weight'] = get_ordered_weight_by_category($category_id, $after, $before);
    $response->set_data($data);

    return $response;
}
```

Here is the JS counterpart using the `woocommerce_admin_report_table` hook :

```
function addWeightToCategories( reportTableData ) {

    const { endpoint, items } = reportTableData;
    if ( 'categories' !== endpoint ) {
        return reportTableData;
    }
  
    reportTableData.headers = [
        ...reportTableData.headers,
        {
            label: 'Weight',
            key: 'category_weight',
            isNumeric: true,
            //isSortable: true
        },
    ];
    reportTableData.rows = reportTableData.rows.map( ( row, index ) => {

        const item = items.data[ index ];
        const newRow = [
            ...row,
            {
                display: item.category_weight,
                value: item.category_weight,
            },
        ];
        return newRow;
    } );
  
    return reportTableData;
}
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'woocommerce_admin_report_table', 'mysupershop', addWeightToCategories );
```

It works just fine, until i try to make this new column sortable in the code above (`isSortable: true`). If i try to sort the report, then i get a error 400 'bad request' on :

```
[hostname]/wp-json/wc-analytics/reports/categories?orderby=category_weight&order=desc&after=2023-10-16T00%3A00%3A00&before=2023-10-16T23%3A59%3A59&page=1&per_page=25&extended_info=true&_locale=user
```

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameters\u00a0: \u00ab\u00a0orderby\u00a0\u00bb","data":{"status":400,"params":{"orderby":"orderby is not one of category_id, items_sold, net_revenue, orders_count, products_count, et category."},"details":{"orderby":{"code":"rest_not_in_enum","message":"orderby is not one of category_id, items_sold, net_revenue, orders_count, products_count, et category.","data":null}}}}
```

There's probably some kind of callback missing for dealing with the "orderby" parameter, but can't find out how it is supposed to be implemented.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: There are some more code samples and tutorials [Here in WooCommerce GitHub repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Awoocommerce%2Fwoocommerce%20woocommerce_admin_report_table&type=code)...